# Geometry Nodes: Pick instance by tile size

Tags: geometry-nodes

I want to put instances on tiles, picking from a collection with cubes of various sizes, so that I can fill the tiles with a minimum number of instances.

For example I have 3 cubes:

1. size 1×1×1 ▪
2. size 2×2×2 ◼
3. size 3×3×3 ⬛

Now I have an object with a geonode tree:

- if a tile size ($x$ and $y$ lengths) is 1×1 then it should automatically pick the ▪ 1×1×1 cube instance on this tile. If a tile size is 1×2, then it should pick 2 cubes of size ▪ 1×1×1;
- if a tile size 2×2 it should pick a cube size of ◼ 2×2×2;
- etc.

Comment: I think the solution will largely depend on if you want to support bigger cubes, as currently geonodes don't support recursion, but just for 3 cubes you can simply duplicate a setup twice.